# Referring to a static member of a subclass

Tags: php, oop

I wish there was a `sub` keyword that would make the code below print `value` on execution. There isn't though and I wonder -  is there an existing way to refer to a member of a subclass?

```
class Main
{
    static function foo()
    {
        echo sub::$variable;
    }
}

class Sub extends Main
{
    static $variable = "value";
}

Sub::foo();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for `static::$variable`. That's called [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) and is available as of PHP 5.3.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Too bad it doesn't work for PHP prior 5.3.