# Call static method from class inheriting Interface

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Referring to a static member of a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828980/referring-to-a-static-member-of-a-subclass)

Please have a look at the following code to understand my problem.

```
<?php

Interface IDoesSomething
{
    public static function returnSomething();
}

abstract class MiddleManClass implements IDoesSomething
{
    public static function doSomething()
    {
        return 1337 * self::returnSomething();
    }
}

class SomeClass extends MiddleManClass
{
    public static function returnSomething()
    {
        return 999;
    }
}

// and now, the vicious call
$foo = SomeClass::doSomething();

/**
 * results in a
 * PHP Fatal error:  Cannot call abstract method IDoesSomething::returnSomething()
 */
?>
```

Is there a way to force abstraction of `returnSomething()` while maintaining the possibility to call the function from a function defined in an abstract "middleman" class? Looks like a bottleneck of PHP to me.

Comment: My question is fundamentally different although the answers are the same.

Comment: your concrete problem is somewhat (not fundamentally) different, but the abstract problem (LSB) is the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you php version >= 5.3 then change

```
public static function doSomething()
{
    return 1337 * self::returnSomething();
}
```

to

```
public static function doSomething()
{
    return 1337 * static::returnSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using statics, it is not very good OOP? Statics are not good for use in inheritance, as they are intended to provide functionality specifically for that class.  This does what you need.

```
<?php

Interface IDoesSomething{
    public function returnSomething();
}

abstract class MiddleManClass implements IDoesSomething{
    public function doSomething(){
        return 1337 * $this->returnSomething();
    }
}

class SomeClass extends MiddleManClass{
    public function returnSomething(){
        return 999;
    }
}

$someClass = new SomeClass();
$foo = $someClass->doSomething();
```

Comment: Not using statics unfortunately doesn't serve my requirements according to the project… in more abstract terms I'd totally agree with you though.

Comment: I'd re-evaluate your design then, as it is unlikely that statics are the only solution...

Answer (score 2):

This issue is known as "late static binding": [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)